# The differences between elements at sets and sets as elements at sets?

Tags: measure-theory

I am a begining learner of set theory, I dont figure out the differences between elements at sets and sets as elements at set. They have same calculation rules? Like follwowing question, I dont know which one is correct, or all wrong?

A={ {1},{2,3},{1,2,3} }   B={ {2},{1,3},{1,2,3} }

Then A U B= { {1}U{2},{2,3}U{1,3}, {1,2,3} }
        or= { {1,2},{1,2,3} }
        0r just { {1,2,3} }

I am a begining learner of set theory. Does anyone know any math online chatting room, I can discuss there, and find the answers of question? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that any element which is either in $A$ or $B$ is in $A\cup B$. So,
$$A\cup B=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}.$$

Don't make the mistake of taking the union of the elements themselves.  For example $\{1\}\in A$, but $1\notin A$.

Comment: Thank you!!!!! I realize many things I did not understand before!!

Answer (score 0):

Neither.

$$A \cup B = \{ \{ 1 \}, \{ 2, 3 \}, \{ 1, 2, 3 \}, \{ 2 \}, \{ 1, 3 \} \}$$

Comment: Thank you, suddenly realize many things that were troubling me. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The set $A \cup B$ is a new set formed by the elements of $A$ and the elements of $B$. So $A \cup B$ is the set given below by Tim.

Comment: thank you!! al of your help me a lot.